# Does gcc support multithreading

Tags: gcc

I have created a new thread in my program with CreaThread() function which is present in windows.h and I compiled with with this command **gcc myprogram.c** but when i started my program it seem that the thread was not started why?i thought that gcc doesn't multithreading can any one help me

Comment: Why - you have bugs in your program. Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc` supports multi-threading. The support is not limited to ability to call `CreateThread` function, there are most importantly [C memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model), [C atomic operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic), [C thread support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)